# How can i exit from my main form if multiple forms are open in vb.net?My code is not working

Tags: vb.net

```
 'Exit from the main form & Display Message about the number of times Users rated.
    Private Sub ExitApp()
        Dim ans As DialogResult
        Dim cns As DialogResult
        ans = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to exit?", "Exit App", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)

        If ans = DialogResult.Yes Then

            cns = MessageBox.Show("Thanks for rating." & " " & "You have been rated" & " " & iOne1 & " " & "Times",
                              "Total Rating", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

        ElseIf cns = DialogResult.OK Then

            me.close()

        End If

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Nested if because you click on OK in next messagebox not the first one...

```
Dim ans As DialogResult
        Dim cns As DialogResult
        ans = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to exit?", "Exit App", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)

        If ans = DialogResult.Yes Then

            cns = MessageBox.Show("Thanks for rating." & " " & "You have been rated" & " " & iOne1 & " " & "Times",
                              "Total Rating", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

            If cns = DialogResult.OK Then

                Me.Close()

            End If
        End If
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Environment.Exit()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit(v=vs.110).aspx) should do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong `if .. else`. Checking for second dialog result need to be nested inside first `if else`. where in your case `ElseIf cns = DialogResult.OK Then` will never be reached.

```
Private Sub ExitApp()
    Dim ans As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to exit?", 
                                              "Exit App", 
                                              MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, 
                                              MessageBoxIcon.Question)

    If ans = DialogResult.Yes Then

        Dim message As String = $"Thanks for rating. You have been rated {iOne1} times"
        Dim cns As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show(message,
                                                  "Total Rating", 
                                                  MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
                                                  MessageBoxIcon.Information)

        If cns = DialogResult.OK Then
            Me.Close()
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Do not declare all variables in the beginning of function. Declare them only when you need, if you declared `cns` only when you created it, then your `ElseIf` will not even compiles, so you will be noticed about your "bug" during compile time.